# How can I center something in Material UI?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

So I have an AppBar component for my Header, and I would like to center the title in the AppBar. As you can see I would have a button on the left and a button on the right. I would have these buttons hugging the left and the right, respectively.

```
const styles = {
  root: {
    flexGrow: 1
  }
};

class Header extends Component {
  render() {
    const { classes } = this.props;
    return (
      <div className={classes.root}>
        <AppBar position="static">
          <Toolbar>
            <LeftButton />
            <Typography variant="h4" color="inherit">
              Title
            </Typography>
            <RightButton />
          </Toolbar>
        </AppBar>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

What would be an approach to center the title?

My initial thought was having a grid of three columns, and then left-aligning the first, center-aligning the second, and right-aligning the third.

Another possibility is to give the title FlexGrow property and then setting text-align to center, but the issue with that approach would be that if the content on the left and right side are unequal, it would be slightly off center.

Comment: Asking for the "best" way is not, well, the best way to ask a question on Stack Overflow :). I've edited your question to simply ask for a way, which is not off-topic.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `withStyles()` that is exported by MaterialUI to put some CSS into components.

And, they have a example that make a [AppBar](https://codesandbox.io/embed/material-demo-sf8yi), i guess will help! that i edit and make [this](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-sf8yi).

In the original code, in the class 'grow', i remove the `flexGrow: 1` and put `margin: "auto"`